# How to assign from a function with multiple outputs?

Tags: r

Is there a way to output e.g. 2 objects without using `list()`?

```
my.fun=function(vector, index)
       {
       a=fun.a(vector, index)
       b=fun.b(vector, index)
       output=list(a,b)
       }
```

Or to output 2 lists of objects? Considering that I could also have:

```
       c=fun.a(vector, index)
       d=fun.b(vector, index)
```

And wanted `list(a,b)` and another `list(c,d)` for the same function.

This is just a small example for what I am looking for, my function is applied to large objects and I export them as a list, however I would like to export also an intermidiate calculation. One option would be to merge all in the same list, but I would like to know if there is another solution to this.

Comment: It was decided that this is a duplicate question 1 year after it was asked?

Comment: you don't need to take it personally, there are many duplicates in StackOverflow and closing and marking duplicates helps keeping the site cleaner and with references to related questions. Since there are many duplicates and the review of all of them may take a long time, it is not always closed immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found `list2env` ideal for what you're describing; the trickiest bit, for me, was working out what to give for the `env` parameter:

```
f=function(){
    list(a=1,b="my string")
}

ret=f()
list2env(ret,env=environment())
#a=ret$a;b=ret$b    #Same as previous line

print(a);print(b)   #1  and "my string"
```

Comment: You may or may not want to use `environment()`.  It returns the Global Environment in this case, but only because it's the current evaluation environment.

Comment: To expand on what @JoshuaUlrich wrote, environment() gives you the current scope (i.e. where your local variables are being stored). This was the SO answer that helped me most in the end: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8773047/841830

Answer (score 11):

You can only `return` one object in a function.  But you have some other options.  You could assign intermediate objects to the global environment (you need to be careful not to overwrite anything) or you could pass an environment to your function and assign objects to it.

Here's an example of the latter suggestion:

```
fun <- function(x, env) {
  env$x2 <- x^2
  x^3
}
set.seed(21)
x <- rnorm(10)
myEnv <- new.env()
fun(x, myEnv)
#  [1]  4.987021e-01  1.424421e-01  5.324742e+00 -2.054855e+00  1.061014e+01
#  [6]  8.125632e-02 -3.871369e+00 -8.171530e-01  2.559674e-04 -1.370917e-08
myEnv$x2
#  [1] 6.288699e-01 2.727464e-01 3.049292e+00 1.616296e+00 4.828521e+00
#  [6] 1.876023e-01 2.465527e+00 8.740486e-01 4.031405e-03 5.728058e-06
```

Comment: +1 At first I thought, "hey that was my answer" and then realized your version was much more structured and well thought out than mine.

Comment: @DWin: yeah, I saw your answer while I was writing mine and debated whether or not to post (since they're similar).  But then I thought it may be helpful to someone to hear the same thing explained in a different way.

Answer (score 5):

The `return()` object needs to be one thing ... a `list` or a `vector`. Since a list can be that "one thing" and a list can hold many things of many classes, all you need to di is initialize a list structure and then push things into it until you are ready to retrun that structure to the calling anvironment.

If you want to "push" individual items into the global (or other environment), you can use `<<-` or `assign`, although that is considered ugly practice and a violation of the paradigm of functional programming.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are limited to using lists, but you can combine them like:

```
> list(list(a=1, b=2), list(c=3, d=4))
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 1

[[1]]$b
[1] 2


[[2]]
[[2]]$c
[1] 3

[[2]]$d
[1] 4
```