# How can I reference the local environment within a function, in R?

Tags: r, namespaces

[This question has been resolved in the [chat room, by Spacedman](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2307138#2307138), but I'm posting it for others' benefit in the future.]

I have a function, `myFunc`, which creates `localFunc` inside of it.  (NB: this is not in a package, but in the global environment.)  I'd like to know where `localFunc` exists in the search path, as I'd like to analyze it via `mvbutils::foodweb`.

Here is an example:

```
myFunc <- function(){
    require(data.table)
    require(mvbutils)
    localFunc <- function(x){
        return(as.data.table(x))
    }
    
    vecPrune <- c("localFunc",ls("package:data.table"))
    ix <- match("data.table",search())
    tmpWeb <- foodweb(where = c(1,ix), prune = vecPrune, plotting = FALSE)
    return(tmpWeb)
}
```

However, a call to `myFunc()` does not seem to indicate that `localFunc` calls `data.table()`.  This is incorrect - what gives?

(NB: The `where` argument specifies the search path.)

---

Update 1: As Tommy and Spacedman point out, the trick is to specify `environment()`.  The call to `foodweb()` refers to `where = c(1, ix)`.  The index `1` is a mistake.  That arose from thinking that `.GlobalEnv`, which is often (always?) the first item in the `search()` vector, is the right place to search.  That is erroneous.  Instead, one should refer to `environment()`, and the correct call is below.  (NB: `ix` specifies the location of `data.table()` in the `search()` output.)

```
tmpWeb <- foodweb(where = c(environment(),ix), prune = vecPrune, plotting = FALSE)
```

This appears in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777882/805808), in a function called `checkScriptDependencies`, which wraps the code from an R script file into a local function, which is then analyzed by `foodweb`.  This is a limited example of how to use `environment()`, and Tommy has given a good explanation of how to use it and similar functions in this context.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To get the current environment, just call `environment()`.

In general, `sys.frame` returns any of the environments currently on the call stack, and `sys.nframe` returns the current depth of the call stack. `sys.frames` returns a list of all environments on the call stack.

`environment(f)` returns the closure environment for a function `f` (where it will look for functions and global variables).

`parent.env(e)` returns the parent environment where it will look if a symbol is not found in `e`.

```
f <- function() {
  function() list(curEnv=environment(), parent=parent.env(environment()), 
          grandParent=parent.env(parent.env(environment())), callStack=sys.frames(), 
          callStackDepth=sys.nframe())
}
g <- function(f, n=2) if (n>2) g(f, n-1) else f()

floc <- f() # generate a local function
g(floc, 3) # call it
```

This will call the local function `floc` with a stack depth of 3. It returns a list with the current environment, it's parent (the local environment in `f`), and it's grand parent (where `f` was defined, so `globalenv`). It also returns the list of stack frames (environments). These are the environments for the recursive calls in `g` (except the last one which is the current environment of `floc`).

Comment: That's what I said in the chatroom. Now @iterator, give him the tick :)

Comment: @Spacedman You had your chance.  :)  Tommy, thanks - your elaboration on what's going on is helpful.  I knew the answer from Spacedman's chat comments, but didn't want to make the question self-answering. I was hoping that someone would come along with a more cogent explanation, as you have done.

Comment: curEnv is the same as callStack[[3]], parent and grandparent are totally different from the other callStacks, why?

Comment: Call stacks are the environments of all the callers, but that's NOT where variables are found. The parent environments are used for that - and they are linked together when the function is DEFINED, whereas calls stacks are linked together when the functions are CALLED. Tricky and confusing, I know...