# R Programming - creates variable in in the environment it was called

Tags: r, variables, environment-variables, environment

I have a function who's task is to create a variable in the parent object. What I want is for the function to create the variable at the level at which it's called.

```
createVariable <- function(var.name, var.value) {
    assign(var.name,var.value,envir=parent.frame())
    }


# Works
testFunc <- function() {
    createVariable("testVar","test")
    print(testVar)
}

# Doesn't work
testFunc2 <- function() {
    testFunc()
    print(testVar)
}

> testFunc()
[1] "test"
> testFunc2()
[1] "test"
Error in print(testVar) : object 'testVar' not found
```

I'm wondering if there's any way to do this without creating the variable in the global environment scope.

Edit: Is there also a way to unit test that a variable has been created?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
createVariable <- function(var.name, var.value) {
  assign(var.name,var.value,envir=parent.env(environment()))
}
```

Edit:
Some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771942/how-can-i-reference-the-local-environment-within-a-function-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439110/what-is-the-difference-between-parent-frame-and-parent-env-in-r-how-do-they). 
With the initial solution, the variable is created in the global env because `parent.env` is the environment in which the function is defined and the `createVariable` function is defined in the global environment.

You might also want to try `assign(var.name,var.value,envir=as.environment(sys.frames()[[1]]))`, which will create it in the highest test function calling `createVariable` in your example (first one on the call stack), in that case however, you will need to remove `print(testVar)` from `testFunc` when you call `testFunc2` because the variable only be created in the environment of `testFunc2`, not `testFunc`. I don't know if that's what you mean by `at the level at which it's called`.

If you run this:

```
createVariable <- function(var.name, var.value) {
  assign(var.name,var.value,envir=as.environment(sys.frames()[[1]]))
  print("creating")
}



testFunc <- function() { 
  createVariable("testVar","test")
  print("func1")
  print(exists("testVar"))
}

testFunc2 <- function() {
 testFunc()
 print("func2")
 print(exists("testVar"))
}

testFunc()
testFunc2()
```

You get

```
> testFunc()
[1] "creating"
[1] "func1"
[1] TRUE
> testFunc2()
[1] "creating"
[1] "func1"
[1] FALSE
[1] "func2"
[1] TRUE
```

Which means `testVar` is in `testFun2`'s environment, not in `testFunc`'s. Creating a new environment as others say might be safer.

Comment: Is there any way to unit test that a variable has been created using testthat?

Comment: you can use `exists("testVar")`

Answer (score 2):

You need the parent environment to do this, not the calling environment:

```
createVariable <- function(var.name, var.value) {
  #use parent.env(environment())
  assign(var.name,var.value,envir=parent.env(environment()))
}


> testFunc()
[1] "test"

> testFunc2()
[1] "test"
[1] "test"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to do this?  Using `assign` can lead to hard to find bugs and other problems.

What might be a better approach is to create a new environment just before calling your function of interest.  Then in your function assign into that new environment (best if the environment is passed to the function, but can use lexical scoping as well to access it).  Then when the function returns you will have the new variable in the environment:

```
createVariable <- function(var.name, var.value, env) {
  env[[var.name]] <- var.value
}

testfunc <- function() {
  tmpenv <- new.env()
  createVariable('x', 1:10, tmpenv)
  print(ls())
  print(ls(env=tmpenv))
  print(tmpenv$x)
}
```

If `createVariable` were defined inside of `testfunc` then it could access `tmpenv` directly without needing it passed down (but passing down is safest when possible).

This version of `createVariable` could even be used more directly to assign in the environment of the calling function (but this becomes more dangerous, too easy to overwrite something in the current environment, or trying to access something by the wrong name due to a small typo):

```
testfunc2 <- function() {
  createVariable('y', 5:1, environment())
  print(ls())
  print(y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new environment and assign the value to it:

```
my.env <- new.env()
my.env$my.object <- runif(1)
```

Then call it using `get`:

```
> my.object # not found in global env
Error: object 'my.object' not found
> get("my.object", envir = my.env)
[1] 0.07912637
```

For your function:

```
createVariable <- function(env.name, var.name, var.value) {
  env.name <- new.env()
  assign(var.name, var.value, envir = env.name)
}
```