# Accessing current environment in R's eval function

Tags: r

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771942/how-can-i-reference-the-local-environment-within-a-function-in-r), `environment()` function is the function to call a current environment.

However, I found that at least that is not the case in `eval` function, with following examples.

```
.env <- new.env()
.env$info$progress <- 3
.expr <- "environment()$info$progress <- 5"
eval(parse(text = .expr), envir = .env, enclos = .env)

> invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

I also tried `assign` function, but it does not work either

```
.env <- new.env()
.env$info$progress <- 3
.expr <- "assign(info$progress, 11, envir = environment())"
eval(parse(text = .expr), envir = .env, enclos = .env)

> Error in assign(info$progress, 11, envir = environment()) :
> invalid first argument
```

So `environment` function failed to find current environment in `eval`.

I would appreciate if anyone lets me know how to access current environment in above examples or how to move-around this issue in `eval`.

Comment: You can't access a function's current environment by calling the function and passing `environment()` as an argument, as that will evaluate `environment()` as the environment where the function is called (e.g. `ff = function(env) c(env, environment()); ff(environment())`). Could you explain your ultimate goal? There, probably, exists a way to build calls and use environments with appropriate R objects rather than characters to parse.

Answer (score 1):

`environment()` does what you think it does.  The issue is with assigning directly to the result of a function call.

```
> new.env()$info$progress <- 3
Error in new.env()$info$progress <- 3 : 
  invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
> .env <- new.env()
> .env$info$progress <- 3
> evalq(identical(environment(), .env), envir = .env)
[1] TRUE
> evalq({ e <- environment(); e$info$progress <- 5 }, envir = .env)
> .env$info
$progress
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal (which I thought was access to a defined environment) can be accomplished by considering the fact that no call to `environment` is needed. That function with a NULL argument doesn't retrieve anything useful. The `.env` object is an environment, so the assignment should just be into it:

```
.env <- new.env()

.env$info$progres <- 3
.expr <- ".env$info$progres <- 5"
eval(parse(text = .expr) )
#------------
> ls(envir=.env)
[1] "info"
> ?get
> get("info", envir=.env)
$progres
[1] 5
```

The environment assignment operation is supposed to put values into the environment of functions. I think it's probably undefined when you make an assignment into an unbound environment. I would not have thought that `environment()$info$progres <- 5` would have succeeded in placing a value into `.env` since the target of `environment(.)<-` was `NULL`.

Responding to your comment: I'm not sure what was meant by "*a* current environment". There is "the current environment" and the `.env`-environment was not *that* environment (nor was it ever that environment, even for an instant). Creating an environment with `new.env` does not make it the current environment. It only creates an environment which allows you to store or retrieve objects in it by referencing its name.

```
 .env <- new.env()
 environment()
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

It isn't even on the search path. It's kind of "on the sidelines" waiting to be referenced.

```
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"         "package:acs"        "package:XML"        "package:acepack"    "package:abind"     
 [6] "package:downloader" "package:forcats"    "package:stringr"    "package:dplyr"      "package:purrr"     
[11] "package:readr"      "package:tidyr"      "package:tibble"     "package:tidyverse"  "tools:RGUI"        
[16] "package:grDevices"  "package:utils"      "package:datasets"   "package:graphics"   "package:rms"       
[21] "package:SparseM"    "package:Hmisc"      "package:ggplot2"    "package:Formula"    "package:stats"     
[26] "package:survival"   "package:sos"        "package:brew"       "package:lattice"    "package:methods"   
[31] "Autoloads"          "package:base"      
> ls(envir=.env)
[1] "info"
```

I find myself wondering if the goal was to use a more object-oriented style, and if so would recommend looking at the `?R6` help page and the section in the R Language Definition entitled: "5 Object-oriented programming".

After navigating through the help pages looking at the code for `getAnywhere`, `?find`, `?ls`, `?objects`, I found a particular use of `apropos` that you might find interesting:

```
apropos("\\.", mode="environment")
[1] ".AutoloadEnv"  ".BaseNamespaceEnv" ".env" ".GenericArgsEnv" ".GlobalEnv" 
[6] ".userHooksEnv"
```

If you use:

```
  apropos("." , mode="environment")`
```

..., constructed with the most generic pattern possible, you will also find the 100 or so ggproto-environments defined by ggplot2-functions, assuming you have that package loaded. I think Hadley's "Advanced Programming" may have more on this topic of interest because he defines a "environment list" class and functions to manipulate them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, that is not what it asked. In this answer, it uses a hard coded variable name ".env", and what I asked was about any function(s) to call a current environment the instead of a hard coded name.