# Assigning output of a function to two variables in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [function with multiple outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216470/function-with-multiple-outputs)

This seems like an easy question, but I can't figure it out and I haven't had luck in the R manuals I've looked at. I want to find `dim(x)`, but I want to assign `dim(x)[1]` to `a` and `dim(x)[2]` to `b` in a single line.

I've tried `[a b] <- dim(x)` and `c(a, b) <- dim(x)`, but neither has worked. Is there a one-line way to do this? It seems like a very basic thing that should be easy to handle.

Comment: I know it is cheating: `tmp <- dim(x); a <- tmp[1]; b <- tmp[2]`

Comment: I'd take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826519/function-returning-more-than-one-value).  The shortest answer is no, R doesn't do that.  The long answer is that you can always make it work for your specific use case.  But there is no "multiple assignment" like in many other languages.

Comment: Thanks @Justin. I know other languages did this, so I was hoping there was an easy way. It's not a huge efficiency problem or anything, just one of R's slightly irritating "quirks" (of which there are many, much as I love the language!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be as simple of a solution as you had wanted, but this gets the job done.  It's also a very handy tool in the future, should you need to assign multiple variables at once (and you don't know how many values you have).

```
Output <- SomeFunction(x)
VariablesList <- letters[1:length(Output)]
for (i in seq(1, length(Output), by = 1)) {
    assign(VariablesList[i], Output[i])
}
```

Loops aren't the most efficient things in R, but I've used this multiple times.  I personally find it especially useful when gathering information from a folder with an unknown number of entries.

EDIT:  And in this case, Output could be any length (as long as VariablesList is longer).

EDIT #2:  Changed up the VariablesList vector to allow for more values, as Liz suggested.

Comment: This is a pretty good solution if you have a lot of pieces of output, although probably not worth it for my situation. I would probably replace your first line with `VariablesList <- letters[1:length(Output)]` though.

Comment: Good idea, I've added that to my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write your own function that will always make a global `a` and `b`.  But this isn't advisable:

```
mydim <- function(x) {
  out <- dim(x)
  a <<- out[1]
  b <<- out[2]
}
```

The "R" way to do this is to output the results as a list or vector just like the built in function does and access them as needed:

```
out <- dim(x)

out[1]

out[2]
```

R has excellent list and vector comprehension that many other languages lack and thus doesn't have this multiple assignment feature.  Instead it has a rich set of functions to reach into complex data structures without looping constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is a way to do this. Really the only way to deal with it is to add a couple of extra lines:

```
temp <- dim(x)
a <- temp[1]
b <- temp[2]
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends what is in `a` and `b`. If they are just numbers try to return a vector like this:

```
dim <- function(x,y) 
    return(c(x,y))
dim(1,2)[1]
# [1] 1
dim(1,2)[2]
# [1] 2
```

If `a` and `b` are something else, you might want to return a list

```
dim <- function(x,y)
    return(list(item1=x:y,item2=(2*x):(2*y)))
dim(1,2)[[1]]
[1] 1 2
dim(1,2)[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4
```

EDIT:

try this: `x <- c(1,2); names(x) <- c("a","b")`

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're suggesting. The `dim()` function is built-in, I just want to assign the dimensions to arbitrary objects `a` and `b` without doing that assignment after calling `dim()`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions-- `names()` only affects the column names of the output though. If you tried something like `a*3` after running that line, you would get an error. Unfortunately, I'm thinking that there isn't a built-in way to do this, so I'll just have to add a couple extra lines to deal with it.