# R - Please explain this code and how to make a function that outputs like it?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am new to R and mostly working with old code written by someone else. And I am trying to create my own R functions.

I found some of the following code used for eigenvalue decomposition.

```
eigenMatrix = eigen(myMatrix)[[2]]
eigenVals = eigen(myMatrix)[[1]]
```

Here there is single function that can output 2 different data structures, being, a vector and a matrix depending of the value in the brackets.

When I search of functions with multiple outputs, they usually use lists to output multiple variables at once which does not work, possibly because of different types.

I don't understand why there are two setts of brackets and how the underlying function would work.

Comment: You should read up on lists in R. Basically using the double bracket ensures that you get the inherent type back. When using only one sets of brackets you get a list no matter the underlying structure.

Comment: Thanks, most posts I found just confused me, until I found the this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050790/how-to-correctly-use-lists-in-r which specifically explains the double bracket which returns the exact value of the list. By the way what should I do with the question now that I understand the answer?

Comment: Also, is there a performance penalty of calling eigen twice a in the sample code?

Comment: Yes there is because it runs the function twice. myList = eigen(myMatrix) and then eigenMatrix = emyList[[2]], eigenVals = emyList[[1]] runs faster. As it gets the result list and gets the values. Thanks.

Comment: If you found an answer you like you should write the answer here and pick your own answer as the solution such that people can understand what the answer is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code takes the eigen function, which returns a list with 2 values.
Then the [[]] are use to extract the first and second items from the list.
The [[]] is needed to return the underlying structure, and is better explained here: [How to Correctly Use Lists in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050790/how-to-correctly-use-lists-in-r)

Also, since the eigen function is run twice the code in the question is inefficient.

```
resultList = eigen(myMatrix)
eigenMatrix = resultList[[2]]
eigenVals = resultList[[1]]
```

This code is better since eigen is run only once and saves the result of the function as a list and then reads the values from the list.

For the function itself can be coaded as any function with multiple outputs such as here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-March/126851.html or here: [How to assign from a function with multiple outputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216470/function-with-multiple-outputs)

The list values can hold any structure and [[]] can be used to return the underlying structure of each value.

Comment: You should select this answer as the solution.