# R: how to get a user-defined function to return multiple outputs?

Tags: r, output, user-defined-functions

I want to make a function that takes one variable and returns multiple outputs, so that I can use the latter for other purposes beyond the function. Take the simplified version below for example:

```
user <- function(x){a <- x+1; a <- a+0.1; b <- a*-1}
sum(a,b)
```

So if I input `user(10)`, `a` would be 11.1, `b` would be -11.1, and `sum(a,b)` would return 0. But currently R is telling me neither object 'a' or object 'b' is found. How can I fix this?

Comment: 1) You can't without resorting to `assign` but 2) Don't.  That isn't really the R way to do it.  If you want to return multiple outputs put them into a list and return the list.

Comment: A stupid question: if my outputs contain both an array and a vector, would a list be the right data structure for them?

Comment: @dasf - yes, a list is the right data structure, it can store both arrays and vectors (and any other data structures).

Comment: Another duplicate (in case you don't like the marked one) [function with multiple outputs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8216470/903061).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really very easy. Just return a list:

```
user <- function(x){a <- x+1; a <- a+0.1; b <- a*-1; return( list(a,b, absum=sum(a,b) )) }
```

I disagree with Dason at least on my first reading. This is exactly the R-way to do it. On my second reading I think he was trying to get across the notion that functions have environments and that you cannot expect variables to persist outside of them unless they are returned in a defined structure. Lists are the typical structure for returning more complex objects. Might be better to return a named list so that the indexing conventions might be available.

Comment: I think you agree with me.  I was saying that direct assigning to 'a' and 'b' from inside the function is not the R way to do it.